# optimize Entity Framework Linq query (selected 1 unexpected field)

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework, linq, query-optimization

All,

Can anyone help me optimize the following EF/Linq query:

The EF/Linq query (taken from LinqPad):

```
Articles
    .AsNoTracking()
    .Where(a => a.Active == "J")
    .SelectMany(a => KerlServices
        .Where(ks => ks.Service.SAPProductNumber == a.SAPProductNumber))
    .Select(ks => new {
        ks.KerlCode,
        ks.Service.SAPProductNumber,
        ks.Service.Type })
    .ToList()
```

The relation between Articles and Services (`ks.Service.SAPProductNumber == a.SAPProductNumber`) is in theory a 1:optional relation with cannot be defined in EF. This is however *not* my question.

The resulting SQL query:

```
SELECT 
    [Join1].[F_SERVICESID] AS [F_SERVICESID], 
    [Join1].[F_KERLCOD] AS [F_KERLCOD], 
    [Join1].[F_SAPARTNUM] AS [F_SAPARTNUM], 
    [Join1].[F_TYPE] AS [F_TYPE]
    FROM  [dbo].[T_ART] AS [Extent1]
    INNER JOIN  (SELECT [Extent2].[F_KERLCOD] AS [F_KERLCOD], [Extent2].[F_SERVICESID] AS [F_SERVICESID], [Extent3].[F_SAPARTNUM] AS [F_SAPARTNUM], [Extent3].[F_TYPE] AS [F_TYPE]
        FROM  [dbo].[T_SERVICESKERL] AS [Extent2]
        INNER JOIN [dbo].[T_SERVICES] AS [Extent3] ON [Extent2].[F_SERVICESID] = [Extent3].[F_ID] ) AS [Join1] ON [Extent1].[F_SAPARTNUM] = [Join1].[F_SAPARTNUM]
    WHERE N'J' = [Extent1].[F_ACTIND]
```

Why does EF generate a query that selects [Join1].[F_SERVICESID]? I don't need this field. Does anyone know a way to prevent this?

Kind regards, Jan.

**ADDITION 1:**

```
KerlServices
    .AsNoTracking()
    .Select(ks => new {
        ks.KerlCode,
        ks.Service.SAPProductNumber,
        ks.Service.Type })
    .Join(
        Articles,
        ks => ks.SAPProductNumber,
        a => a.SAPProductNumber,
        (ks, a) => new { ks, a.Active })
    .Where(ksa => ksa.Active == "J")
    .Select(ksa => ksa.ks)
    .ToList()
```

results in:

```
SELECT 
    [Extent1].[F_SERVICESID] AS [F_SERVICESID], 
    [Extent1].[F_KERLCOD] AS [F_KERLCOD], 
    [Extent2].[F_SAPARTNUM] AS [F_SAPARTNUM], 
    [Extent2].[F_TYPE] AS [F_TYPE]
    FROM   [dbo].[T_SERVICESKERL] AS [Extent1]
    INNER JOIN [dbo].[T_SERVICES] AS [Extent2] ON [Extent1].[F_SERVICESID] = [Extent2].[F_ID]
    INNER JOIN [dbo].[T_ART] AS [Extent3] ON [Extent2].[F_SAPARTNUM] = [Extent3].[F_SAPARTNUM]
    WHERE N'J' = [Extent3].[F_ACTIND]
```

This 'improvement' does not answer my own question, but the result surely looks prettier to me.

**UPDATE 1:**

The query in Ivan Stoev's answer produces the following SQL:

```
SELECT 
    [Extent1].[F_SERVICESID] AS [F_SERVICESID], 
    [Extent1].[F_KERLCOD] AS [F_KERLCOD], 
    [Extent2].[F_SAPARTNUM] AS [F_SAPARTNUM], 
    [Extent2].[F_TYPE] AS [F_TYPE]
    FROM  [dbo].[T_SERVICESKERL] AS [Extent1]
    INNER JOIN [dbo].[T_SERVICES] AS [Extent2] ON [Extent1].[F_SERVICESID] = [Extent2].[F_ID]
    WHERE  EXISTS (SELECT 
        1 AS [C1]
        FROM [dbo].[T_ART] AS [Extent3]
        WHERE (N'J' = [Extent3].[F_ACTIND]) AND ([Extent3].[F_SAPARTNUM] = [Extent2].[F_SAPARTNUM])
    )
```

Comment: I'm running out of ideas. EF version? database type - Sql Server? have you checked it inside the VS instead of LinqPad?

Comment: @IvanStoev: Good idea to see what SQL is generated when not using LinqPad. Perhaps LinqPad is responsible.

Comment: See my updated answer. I've found similar cases when working on another SO issue, and there is no problem at all from the query materialization perspective.

Answer (score 1):

> Why does EF generate a query that selects [Join1].[F_SERVICESID]? I don't need this field.

That's weird if true, I have no explanation for that.

> Can anyone help me optimize the following EF/Linq query

It's worth trying the following, which for me represents the most logical way to retrieve the data in question:

```
KerlServices
    .AsNoTracking()
    .Select(ks => new {
        ks.KerlCode,
        ks.Service.SAPProductNumber,
        ks.Service.Type })
    .Where(ks => Articles.Any(a => a.Active == "J" && a.SAPProductNumber == ks.SAPProductNumber)
    .ToList()
```

**UPDATE:** Recently I've encountered that EF includes some additional fields in the generated SQL query when dialing with foreign key relations. These fields are **not** included in the projected result, so I think you should not worry about. Take any of the queries above, execute it inside the real code environment (VS Debug) and check the the projected list - I'm pretty sure the field in question will not be there.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. So cool that you actually mention the *exact* query I had before I started optimizing. I added the generated SQL of that as **UPDATE 1** to my original question.

Comment: @JanC.deGraaf  The Sql query looks exactly how I would hand write it, except the aliases of course and that weird column. So whatever we do, you get that `[F_SERVICEID]`. Btw, what is the type of the `KerlCode` property?

Comment: The type of the `KerlCode` property is required-string-length-5. In the database it is `nvarchar(5), not null`.

Comment: And, yes, EF very often (always?) seems to add the FK field to the select list.

Comment: You are correct that these extra fields are not included in the projected result, but these extra columns *are* selected and transferred from the DB-server to the EF-client, consuming valuable bandwidth.